# ELF binaries in different linux distibutions

Tags: linux, elf

If I have an ELF binary file, generated in Ubuntu using gcc or QtCreater, can this binary be executed in another linux distribution, such as RHEL?
( I guess pure CLI programs can, but GUI programs depends) 
Can 32-bit binary run on 64-bit machine, or vice versa?

Comment: It depends on couple of factors (linkage, dependencies, etc ...)

Comment: The x86_64 program won't run on the IA-32 system. However, the IA-32 program should run on the x86_64 system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. ELF binaries, as long as the architecture is compatible, can be run on different systems. That is, 32-bit x86 ELF can be run on a 64-bit x64 system.

That said, it does not mean that your program will even start. It still requires that all runtime dependencies are met. That notably includes every shared library used by the program. If they are not available in the running machine the program will not work.

You can check the needed shared libraries with `objdump -p <program | grep NEEDED`. If they are not available for your taget system, you can also distribute the SO files and modify the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to load them.

But even if the shared libraries are satisfied, the program is not guaranteed to work properly. You still may miss configuration files, fonts, system services, kernel features... You will have to test it on every distribution you intend to support.

PS: all that said, the issue is not conceptually different between CLI and GUI programs. It is just that GUI programs tend to have so many more dependencies...